# Rust lifetime issue

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
pub fn get_header_authorization() -> (&str, &str) {
    dotenv().ok();
    let str = std::env::var("HEADER_AUTHORIZATION").expect("HEADER AUTHORIZATION must be set!");
    let header:Vec<&str> = str.split('&').collect();
    let (a, b) = (header[0], header[1]);
    (a, b)
}
```

```
#[test]
fn test() {
    let authorization = get_header_authorization();
    assert_eq!(authorization.0, "Authorization")
}
```

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
   --> src\json_function.rs:173:45
    |
173 | pub fn get_header_authorization() -> (&str, &str) {
    |                                             ^ expected named lifetime parameter
    |
```

Comment: Why are you returning `&str` instead of `String`?

Answer (score 1):

Rust can only infer the lifetimes of return types if you have a reference in the arguments, in which case it'll infer that the lifetimes of the parameters and return types has to be the same. This is why you get this particular error. That isn't the problem with the code, though.

The problem is that `std::env::var` returns a `Result<String, VarError>`, so the type of `str` is String and that String is owned by the function. You then try to return a reference to that String from the function. But when the function returns the String it owns will go out of scope and get dropped and all references to it will become invalid. Rust doesn't allow this. To get around this, you can just return the Strings directly:

```rust
pub fn get_header_authorization() -> (String, String) {
    dotenv().ok();
    let str = std::env::var("HEADER_AUTHORIZATION").expect("HEADER AUTHORIZATION must be set!");
    let mut header = str.split('&').map(str::to_owned);
    
    let (a, b) = (header.next().unwrap(), header.next().unwrap());
    (a, b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let (a, b) = (header[0], header[1]);
 (a, b)
```

These are the 2 last lines of the function.

As pointed out in the answer by [@isaactfa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68300359/6909825), you are returning references that could go out of scope at any time and cause issues.

The best way to understand how Rust asks for a lifetime is to first understand the [Lifetime Elission Rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision) in Rust.
There are 3 rules that rust uses to implicitly assign lifetime parameters to the function's input parameters and the return value of the function, but all of this will depend on the input parameters.
In your case, the function does not have any concrete input parameter by reference, so Rust could not automatically assign the lifetimes.

**Solution**

Return `String` Objects in the tuple instead by doing it as pointed out by [@issactfa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68300359/6909825) above or this way

```
pub fn get_header_authorization() -> (String, String) {
    // dotenv().ok();
    let str = std::env::var("HEADER_AUTHORIZATION").expect("HEADER AUTHORIZATION must be set!");
    let header: Vec<&str> = str.split('&').collect();
    let (a, b) = (header[0], header[1]);
    (a.to_string(), b.to_string())
}
```

Pay attention to the return value `(a.to_string(), b.to_string())`

If you still need help, familiarize yourself with both the ownership rules in Rust and, the [concept of Lifetime](https://youtu.be/FF0iNjif1Mo) in Rust and the [Lifetime Elision Rules](https://youtu.be/NI1Z3EbSbeE) or you can take a look at this detailed 3 series video where I explained Lifetimes in Rust and also explained the 3 [Lifetime Elision Rules with Examples](https://youtu.be/NI1Z3EbSbeE?t=354).